# Retry and Failure queue prioritization in NiFi

Tags: http, error-handling, apache-nifi

I have a queue at NiFi that contains the items that will be processed through an API query (invokeHTTP). These items can be processed and return the answer with the data correctly (status 200), they can not be found (status 404) and also a failure (status 500).
However, in the case of status 404 and 500, false negatives can happen, so if I consult the same data that gave an error again, it returns with status 200. But there are cases that there really is a failure and it is not a false negative.

[image]

So I created a queue for retry and failure for them to enter involeHTTP again and consult the API. I put an expiration time of 5 minutes so that the data that is really at fault is not forever consulting the API.

However, I wanted to prioritize this Failure and Retry queue, so that by the time a data reaches it, it will be consulted in the API again, in front of the standard processing queue, so as not to lose the data that gave false negatives.

Is it possible to do this treatment with this self relationship or do you need a new flowfile?

Answer (score 0):

Each queue can have a prioritizer configured on the queue's settings. Currently you have two separate queues for InvokeHttp, the failure/retry queue and the incoming queue from the matched relationship of EvaluateJsonPath. You need to put a funnel in front of InvokeHttp and send both of these queues to the funnel, then the funnel to InvokeHttp. This way you can create a single incoming queue to InvokeHttp and configure the prioritizer there.

In order to prioritize it correctly, you may want to use Flow File Attribute prioritizer. You would use UpdateAttribute to add a "priority" attribute to each flow file, the ones for failure/retry get priority "A" and the others get priority "B" (or anything that sorts after A).

Comment: Very interesting the strategy. But how do I make sure that the data that is really giving an error and is not a false negative so that it will not be consulting the API forever? Would you use file routing?

Comment: Well the point of having separate "failure" and "retry" is that "failures" are not supposed to ever work, so normally you wouldn't route this back in a loop, but I guess maybe you have a timing problem where something isn't ready yet? I guess you can create a retry counter in an attribute and after X number of retries route it somewhere else

Comment: Old post but the approach is still accurate - https://kisstechdocs.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/creating-a-limited-failure-loop-in-nifi/

Comment: my error handling basically is that the API sometimes returns an error (500), but if you make the request again it returns success (200). The big problem is that when the data arrives in invokeHTTP, it is just a string with no other attributes. Thanks for post.